# ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `libYYY.a` not a dynamic executable

Tags: c++, cmake, ldd

I'm running CMake by this command:

```sh
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=deps/build/destdir/usr/local -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=ON ..
```

But, this error is received:

> ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for
> `/home/m3/repos/cpp-service/deps/build/destdir/usr/local/lib/libopenvdb.a'
>
> ```
>     not a dynamic executable
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /usr/local/lib64/cmake/OpenVDB/FindOpenVDB.cmake:550
> (get_prerequisites)   linux.cmake:29 (find_package)
> CMakeLists.txt:28 (include)

[image: Screenshot]

## Problem

I think the problem is due to the fact that I have `libopenvdb.a` installed in two paths:

1. `/usr/local/lib64/` inside my system filesystem
2. `deps/build/destdir/usr/local/lib/` inside my source code tree

I intend to use the OpenVDB inside my source code tree, not the system one. I don't have enough CMake expertise. How can I avoid such conflicts?

Comment: The .a suffix means it is a static library when cmake expects a dynamic .so library. Please post you CmakeLists.txt file.

Comment: @U.W. You were right :) The CMake file was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @U.W. commented, the CMake file was problematic.

In my CMake file I had such statements:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/usr/local/lib64/cmake/OpenVDB/")
find_package(OpenVDB REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(
   ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
                         OpenVDB::openvdb)
```

The error got resovled by replacing the above statements with these ones:

```
list(
  APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  "/home/m3/repos/cpp-service/deps/build/destdir/usr/local/lib/cmake/OpenVDB")
set(OPENVDB_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(OpenVDB REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(
  ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
                         OpenVDB::openvdb)
```

Comment: You almost certainly want to write `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` instead of `/home/m3/repos/cpp-service/deps/build`.

Comment: @AlexReinking Right :) I ended up using paths like this: `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/deps-extra/eigen-3.3.9/cmake/")`